# My spring batch step keeps looping after reaching build

Tags: spring-batch

This section reads in the file from our server, processes it, writes it out and archives it.

```
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        log.info("Made if to step1");
        System.out.println("Made it to Step 1");
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<PaymentTransaction, PaymentTransaction>chunk(10)
                .reader(paymentTransactionItemReader())
                .writer(paymentTransactionItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDecider decider() {
        System.out.println("Made it to the decider");
        return (jobExecution, stepExecution) -> new FlowExecutionStatus("Success"); }

    @Bean
    public FlowJobBuilder job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("BenefitIssuance")
                .start(step1())
                .next(decider())
                .on("Success")
                .end()
                .build();
    }
```

However when it reaches the build() step at the end, it loops back to the reader

Comment: Is it intended that the `job()` method returns a `FlowJobBuilder` and not a `Job`? Where is the definition of the job your are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't see why the `job()` method returns a `FlowJobBuilder` and not a `Job`. The following job definition does not loop back on the same step:

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobs.get("job")
            .start(step1())
               .next(decider())
               .on("Success")
               .end()
               .build()
            .build();
}
```